# D3 Directive- gettng error for invalid value for path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I am new to using D3 and am trying to write out a directive to create an area chart. I thought I had written out the directive correctly but am getting an error about an invalid value for the path. I believe it has to do with the date not being parsed correctly. I have spent a lot of time trying to fix it with no results. I am hoping to have someone look it over as I am probably missing something. The data comes in from an JSON array in the controller.

```
$scope.dataArray =  [
    {"date":"2014-10-05T15:48:52-07:00","value":16}, 
    {"date":"2014-07-15T22:26:11-07:00","value":24}, 
    {"date":"2014-09-23T18:52:10-07:00","value":54},
     and so on . . .
  ];
```

Hope a new pair of eyes will find what I'm doing wrong.

```
(function(){
'use strict';

 angular.module('d3AngularApp')
    .directive('testAreaChart', ['d3Service', function (d3Service){

    var link = function($scope, $el, $attrs){

    d3Service.d3().then(function (d3){

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = $el[0].clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = $el[0].clientHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select($el[0])
        .append("svg");

    var updateGraph = function (){

            var data = $scope.chartdata;

            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.date = parseDate(d.date);
                d.value = +d.value;
              });

            var area = d3.svg.area()
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                .y0(height)
                .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });


            svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
              .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



              x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
              y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

              svg.append("path")
                  .datum(data)
                  .attr("class", "area")
                  .attr("d", area);

              svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "x axis")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                  .call(xAxis);

              svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis")
                  .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                  .attr("y", 6)
                  .attr("dy", ".71em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "end")
                  .text("Price ($)");

              resize();
            };


            function resize(){

                var newWidth = $el[0].clientWidth,
                newHeight = (Math.round($el[0].clientWidth * .75));

                svg.attr('width', newWidth);
                svg.attr('height', newHeight )
            }

            $scope.$on('windowResize', resize);
            $scope.$watch('chartdata', updateGraph);
    })
 }

      return {
         restrict: 'E',
         template: '<div class="areachart col-md-12"></div>',
         replace: true,
         scope : {chartdata: '='},
         link: link
      }

    }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I needed. D3 was reading my dates as strings and I needed to add a function to change all the date strings into date values.

```
var data = $scope.chartdata;

function formatDate(input) { 
   return new Date(input);
  }

 for (i=0; i < data.length; i++){
    data[i].date = formatDate(data[i].date);
  }
```

Graph worked after adding this.

Answer (score 0):

Watches usually fire when they are instantiated (before there is data on the scope), so you are probably running updateGraph when chartData is undefined. Try changing `$scope.$watch('chartdata', updateGraph);` to `$scope.$watch('chartdata', function(d) { if(d) { updateGraph() }; });`

Comment: I've been playing with the code a bit. It definitely has to deal with the date. when the area graph goes to graph the data, the date value keeps coming up as NAN. It reads the value. I updated the initial post to show an example of what the data array looks like.

Comment: My point is that the first time updateGraph fires, there probably is no data at all. Please post a working example, as that will help us diagnose the exact problem. You can also instrument the code yourself by putting in ```console.log($scope.chartdata.length)```.